# Firing 3rd party js tags via GTM on specific pages

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm implementing Google Tag Manager on my website.

The issue is, I want our live chat to only be on certain pages and not others. You're probably thinking this is quite easy (and it may be) but let me explain why this is difficult.

For example I want live chat widget on the following pages:

/safety
 /blog
 /terms

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwcbwi06box5iw9/shot_161122_101430.png?dl=0

but I don't want it on any other page of my website. The problem is, when the tag is fired on 'some pages' all these conditions must be true .. therefore my approach is obviously false, as the user cannot be on all 3 pages at once.

What am I missing? I'm sure there must be another way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use either three rules with exact matches for the page path or a single rule with a regular expression, e.g.

```
page path matches ^/safety$\|^/blog$|^/terms$
```

where "^" means "starts with", $ means "ends with" and the pipe character "|" means "or".